# Feedback about statistical and numerical illiteracy-examples website?

Tags: examples, statistics

I have assembled a list of statistical and numerical illiteracy examples in the media, as they appeared in Chance News online (a statistics wiki) between 2005 and 2014.  See "Collected Forsooths at https://www.causeweb.org/wiki/chance/index.php/Collected_Forsooths. I would appreciate feedback about its usefulness in the classroom.

Comment: Welcome to the site! There are two somewhat related questions: [Impressive common misleading interpretations in statistics to make students aware of](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/impressive-common-misleading-interpretations-in-statistics-to-make-students-awar) and [Examples of Innumeracy](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1572/examples-of-innumeracy); the latter mentions [your resource in an answer](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/4191/143)

Comment: Don't you mean "innumeracy" rather than "illiteracy"?

Comment: Great site and many thanks for these other links.  Please, if anyone else has more, post them.  I am also looking for the third in the trilogy... illiterate, innumerate and aspatial

Comment: Sorry about the "illiteracy" term - I know better but am always in too much of a hurry!  Besides Paulos, see MacNeal's Mathsemantics (http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/938114.Mathsemantics); this is 2nd ed. of book I read, and used in college classes, many years ago.